# Consider $g(\theta)=(r\cos\theta , r\sin \theta)$.Which is the image of $g'(\theta)h+ g(\theta)$, with $h \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $r>0$. Consider $g:(0,2\pi) \to S'=\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2=r^2\}$
defined by $g(\theta)=(r\cos\theta , r\sin \theta)$.
which is the image of $g'(\theta)h+ g(\theta)$, with $h \in \mathbb{R}$?

I would like a tip to develop this exercise. I thought about fixing the $\theta$ and varying $h$, because I think if varying $\theta$ and $h$ the image is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Maybe separate in cases, if $h$ is $0$, the image of that expression is the image of $g$ itself and then study $g$ calculated in $\theta + h$.

Comment: Is $h$ fixed? What is (are) your independent variable(s)? If you fixed $\theta$ and vary $h$ you're looking at a line.

Comment: yes, $h$ is fixed. $\theta$ is the independent variable.

Comment: What do you mean with $g'(\theta)?$ Which derivative? Are you sure $h$ is not in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It's unclear what "image" the question is asking for. But if $h$ and $\theta$ are both allowed to vary, then the given expression takes every value in $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\ge r^2\}$ except for $(r,0)$.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case, but when $\theta \; \text{and} \; r$ vary and fixated respectively, the image of $g'$ is just $\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = r^2\}$, and when multiplied by $h; \hspace{20px} x^2 + y^2 \geq r^2$